# Bokeh Server Files: load_from_config = False

Tags: python, python-2.7, bokeh

on Bokeh 0.7.1

I've noticed that when I run the bokeh-server, files appear in the directory that look like bokeh.data, bokeh.server, and bokeh.sets, if I use the default backend, or redis.db if I'm using redis.  I'd like to run my server from a clean start each time, because I've found that if the files exist, over time, my performance can be severely impacted.

While looking through the API, I found the option to turn "load_from_config" from True to False.  However, tinkering around with this didn't seem to resolve the situation (it seems to only control log-in information, on 0.7.1?).  Is there a good way to resolve this and eliminate the need for me to manually remove these files each time?  What is the advantage of having these files in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

These files are to store data and plots persistently on a `bokeh-server`, for instance if you want to publish a plot so that it will always be available. If you are just using the server locally and always want a "clean slate" you can run with `--backend=memory` to use the in-memory data store for Bokeh objects.